# Jquery .easing errors jQuery.easing[this.easing]

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-easing

I have done absolutely everything to try and fix my code:   JQuery libraries (Ui’s, Core’s, Plugins) .etc, but can't fix this

```
            $('.heading').click(function() {
                console.log("Clicked", $(this));
                $(this).animate({'color':'blue'},500,'easeOutBounce'); // example 1 , there not work and attempt error
               // $(this).animate({'color':'blue'},500,'leaner');  // example 2 , there not work BUT NOT attempt error
            });
        });
```

[There is  link for see console errors](https://codepen.io/david262929/pen/dybzqJa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the latest jQueryUI for the easing options.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.heading').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({'color':'blue'},1000,'easeOutBounce'); 
    $(this).css({ transition: "transform 0.5s",
                  transform:"translate(100px,100px)"});
  });
});
```

```css
.heading{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<h1 class="heading">Epanalepis de Fato Hominis</h1>
```

Comment: but when I changed color animation to transfor animation it not working there https://codepen.io/david262929/pen/OJLxpOL

Comment: @DavidGhazaryan  use CSS transitions. I have updated the solution

Comment: thanks for help, but I found most useful [plugin-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.transit) for it